# Dividing Monthly cost to daily records In SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server

I have two types of costs in my table, How to show all monthly cost as daily for that specific month I mean the monthly cost (5000) need to dived by 30 days  (2018-05-16- 2018-06-15) and daily amount 5000/30=166.66 must showing on my daily report.

Thanks for the help .
[image]

```
SELECT  [ExpensesID]
  ,[ExpDate]
  ,[ExpsType]
  ,[ExpDetails]
  ,[ExpAmount]
  ,[USDRate]
  ,[ExpenseBy]
  FROM [PSationMIS].[dbo].[Expenses]

ExpensesID  ExpDate ExpsType    ExpDetails  ExpAmount   USDRate ExpenseBy

1   2018-05-16  Daily   Lunch Cost  40.000  71.000  NULL
2   2018-05-16  Monthly Office Rent 5000.000    71.000  NULL
```

I want to see the result like this:

```
ExpensesID  ExpDate ExpsType    ExpDetails  ExpAmount   USDRate ExpenseBy

1   2018-05-16  Daily   Lunch Cost  40.000  71.000  NULL
2   2018-05-16  Monthly Office Rent 166.66.000  71.000  NULL (As daily cost)
3   2018-05-16  Monthly Office Rent 166.66.000  71.000  NULL
4   2018-05-16  Monthly Office Rent 166.66.000  71.000  NULL
5   2018-05-16  Monthly Office Rent 166.66.000  71.000  NULL
......
30  2018-05-16  Monthly Office Rent 166.66.000  71.000  NULL
```

I added a computed column on the table to count numbers of the day and then by using datediff function I divided the cost by numbers of the day .

Dear EzLo Could you please generate the number of the days for this query:

```
    SELECT 

 [ExpensesID]
      ,[ExpDate]
      ,[ExpsType]
      ,[ExpDetails]
      ,[ExpAmount]
      ,[USDRate]
      ,[ExpenseBy], DATEADD(MONTH, 1, ExpDate)
      ,sum(CASE
              WHEN ExpsType = 'monthly' and  ExpDate between ExpDate and DATEADD(MONTH, 1, ExpDate)  THEN ExpAmount/ DATEDIFF(DAY,ExpDate,enddate)   else ExpAmount
           END) AS CostPerDay
  FROM [Expenses]

  group by [ExpensesID]
      ,[ExpDate]
      ,[ExpsType]
      ,[ExpDetails]
      ,[ExpAmount]
      ,[USDRate]
      ,[ExpenseBy]
```

Comment: if you share the query, it will be appreciated and help us in helping you.

Comment: What you have tried so far. Write input data, your query and where you are facing the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply... Please check the edited question.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this solution. We calculate each month's total in the first CTE, then using a recursive CTE we generate 30 rows for each month with the daily amount and finally use `UNION ALL` to join the split monthly rent with other expenses.

```
;WITH MonthTotals AS
(
    SELECT
        Year = YEAR(T.ExpDate),
        Month = MONTH(T.ExpDate),
        Total = SUM(T.ExpAmount)
    FROM
        [PSationMIS].[dbo].[Expenses] AS T
    GROUP BY
        YEAR(T.ExpDate),
        MONTH(T.ExpDate)
),
RecursiveDailyRent AS -- Generate 30 rows with the same daily amount (per month) 
(
    SELECT
        T.Year,
        T.Month,
        DailyTotal = T.Total / 30,
        LoopCounter = 1
    FROM
        MonthTotals AS T

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        R.Year,
        R.Month,
        DailyTotal = DailyTotal,
        LoopCounter = R.LoopCounter + 1
    FROM
        RecursiveDailyRent AS R
    WHERE
        R.LoopCounter <= 30
)
SELECT  
    [ExpensesID],
    [ExpDate],
    [ExpsType],
    [ExpDetails],
    [ExpAmount],
    [USDRate],
    [ExpenseBy]
FROM
    [PSationMIS].[dbo].[Expenses] AS E
UNION ALL
SELECT
    [ExpensesID] = NULL,
    [ExpDate] = DATEFROMPARTS(R.Year, R.Month, 1),
    [ExpsType] = 'Monthly Office',
    [ExpDetails] = 'Rent',
    [ExpAmount] = R.DailyTotal,
    [USDRate] = NULL,
    [ExpenseBy] = NULL
FROM 
    RecursiveDailyRent AS R
ORDER BY
    ExpDate
```

Make sure to review the columns of the union all's 2nd select, as I wrote some by default.

---

**EDIT**: Query to generate the amount of days dynamically (make sure to review and add the proper `UNION` to the final result.

```
;WITH DailyRent AS
(
    SELECT 
        [ExpensesID]
        ,[ExpDate]
        ,[ExpsType]
        ,[ExpDetails]
        ,[ExpAmount]
        ,[USDRate]
        ,[ExpenseBy], 
        DATEADD(MONTH, 1, ExpDate) AS ExpDateNextMonth
        ,sum(CASE
              WHEN ExpsType = 'monthly' and  ExpDate between ExpDate and DATEADD(MONTH, 1, ExpDate)  THEN ExpAmount/ DATEDIFF(DAY,ExpDate,enddate)   else ExpAmount
           END) AS CostPerDay
    FROM 
        [Expenses]
    WHERE
        ExpsType = 'monthly'
    group by 
        [ExpensesID]
      ,[ExpDate]
      ,[ExpsType]
      ,[ExpDetails]
      ,[ExpAmount]
      ,[USDRate]
      ,[ExpenseBy]
),
RecursiveDailyRent AS
(
    SELECT
        CostPerDay = T.CostPerDay,
        ExpDate = T.ExpDate,
        ExpDateNextMonth = T.ExpDateNextMonth
    FROM
        DailyRent AS T

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        CostPerDay = R.CostPerDay,
        ExpDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, R.ExpDate),
        ExpDateNextMonth = R.ExpDateNextMonth
    FROM
        RecursiveDailyRent AS R
    WHERE
        DATEADD(DAY, 1, R.ExpDate) < R.ExpDateNextMonth
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    RecursiveDailyRent AS R
```

Note that I filtered only the `monthly` expenses at the first CTE, since I believe those are the only ones that need to be split daily. You can `UNION ALL` these results with the `non monthly` expenses at the end.

Comment: A couple of possible improvements (depending on the requirement): use DATESUB and DATEDIFF in MonthTotals query to work out the actual number of days in the month to ExpDate (it's 31 in the example given, not 30); and correct for rounding errors by calculating the amount left to be used up on the final loop of the recursive part.

Comment: @SimonSellick You pointed out good things. The solution I thought was to serve as a base, the OP can start tweaking here and there to fit his logic (since he didn't explain it in detail).

Comment: You are right Simon Sellick,
I added a computed column on the table to count numbers of the day and then by using datediff function I divided the cost by numbers of the day . Dear SimonSellick Could you please generate the number of the days for this query:

Comment: @EzLo Thanks for the update. but why it show 32 rows, the maximum days should be 31.I couldn't find the error.

Comment: @Ash the recursive condition was wrong, it was `<= R.ExpDateNextMonth` and it should be  `< R.ExpDateNextMonth` (without equals). I've edited it now.